# How to do this in a proper way? With good calculation

Tags: calculus

"Seven numbers follow after eachother and have the sum 1 617. Which is the smallest of those seven numbers"?
The answer is:225

I already know the answer but I want to know how to calculate this problem properly.I will be very thankful if you can tell me how to solve this with a good calculation.

Comment: By the way, the answer is not $225$. It is $225$ if they are consecutive **odd** numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be the smallest one of those. Then:

$$(x) + (x + 1) + (x+2) + ... + (x + 6) = 1617$$

From which you can find $x$.

Answer (score 2):

One can take advantage of symmetry by letting the middle number be $m$. Then the numbers are $m-3,m-2,m-1,m,m+1,m+2,m+3$, sum $7m$. So $7m=1617$, $m=231$. Now count backwards $3$ times, we get $228$.

**Remark:** Let us change the problem slightly, and ask for consecutive **odd** numbers. Using the above strategy, we can assume that the numbers are $m-5, m-3,m-1,m,m+1,m+3,m+5$. Again, we get $m=231$, but now counting backwards by twos we get the smallest is $225$.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the two other answers are correct.  But I think my way is (slightly) easier and simpler, although in essence it is equivalently the same.

Find the *average* of the numbers. 1,617/7 = 231. As the 7 numbers are evenly spaced the average number will be the middle number.  So the smallest number is 231 - 3 = 228.

Or more formally and precise:

Let x be the *middle* number.  Then the numbers range from (x - 3) to (x + 3). [Or in general from x - n to x + n]. If you add them each x - i term is matched with an x + i term.  So the total sum is 7x [or in general nx].

So the middle/average number is 1,617/7 =  231 and the smallest number is 231 - 3 = 228.

As pointed in the comments 228 $\ne$ 225.  If the numbers were required to be odd, then, the average/middle number is still 231 and if we go down three terms, 229,227, 225 the smallest number is 225.

If you claimed the numbers were consecutive multiples of 3 you'd still get the middle number was 231 and the smallest term is 222.

If you claimed the numbers were consecutive multiples of 11 ....

....

[Okay, you *can't* claim they are consecutive even numbers or multiples or 9 or anything that 231 isn't.]

[  But you can claim s that if there are 7 numbers each 4 apart, for example, from the one before that add to 1,617, you can conclude, yet again, the middle/average number is 231 and the lowest number is 219 (then 223, 227, 231,235, 239 and finally 243), even though none are actually multiples of 4.]

Comment: Hmm, how strange.  I swear when I started to type this I hadn't seen Andre Nicolas's answer but there was another about summing from n to n + 7.  Andre's answer is, of course, the same as mine he got it up first.